# Filtering, ordering and pagination in clean architecture django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, clean-architecture

I recently used clean architecture for my project. The project is divided into several sections according to clean architecture, each of which performs its tasks. But what confused me is that, I do not know how can I use filter and pagination class in this architecture.

[image]

Comment: Clean-architecture is not a good match for Django applications, as it already has its own layers, ORM, MVC and modular architecture.